# Winner/Looser Contingency-Table

Tags: r, frequency, contingency

I have a data frame with around 200 columns and want to generate a 2x2 contingency table.
My code looks like this:

```
d <- structure(list(Time=structure(17942:17947, class="Date"),
x1=c(NA, NA, 17L, 29L, 27L, 10L), x2=c(30L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 11L,
24L), x3=c(NA, 23L, 22L, 27L, 21L, 26L), x4=c(30L, 28L, 23L,
24L, 10L, 17L), x5=c(12L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 30L, 26L)),
row.names=c(NA, 6L), class="data.frame")

x <- t(apply(d[,-1], 1, function(x) x > median(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
nr <- nrow(x)
dx <- diff(x)

lw <- (dx == 1)*1
wl <- (dx == -1)*2
dd <- (dx == 0)
ww <- (dd & x[-nr,] == 1)*3
ll <- (dd & x[-nr,] == 0)*4

tab <- c("lose/win", "win/lose", "win/win", "lose/lose")[lw + wl + ww + ll]

d0 <- d
d0[-1,-1] <- tab
d0
```

This is the output:

```
#         Time       x1        x2       x3        x4        x5
# 1 2019-02-15     <NA>        30     <NA>        30        12
# 2 2019-02-16     <NA> lose/lose     <NA>  lose/win lose/lose
# 3 2019-02-17     <NA> lose/lose win/lose   win/win lose/lose
# 4 2019-02-18 lose/win lose/lose lose/win  win/lose lose/lose
# 5 2019-02-19  win/win lose/lose win/lose lose/lose  lose/win
# 6 2019-02-20 win/lose lose/lose lose/win lose/lose   win/win
```

I'm looking for a efficient way to count all four possible combinations for each row separately ignoring the NAs.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: apply(df[,-1], 1, table)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
tbl <- reshape2::melt(d0[-1, ], id.vars = "Time")[3]
tbl <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(tbl$value), "/"))
tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
```

A contingency table.

```
xtabs(~ ., tbl)
#      V2
#V1     lose win
#  lose   10   5
#  win     4   3
```

Alternative way.

```
table(tbl)
#      V2
#V1     lose win
#  lose   10   5
#  win     4   3
```